# sql like to find orders in specific date

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have a table of orders. the column dateordered represents the date in which an order occurred. That column is a datetime. Looking like: YYYY-MM-DD.

I have the following query.

```
select * from orders_ where dateordered like '08%' -- for orders which occurred in augus
```

but I'm not getting any results, when I should.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: None of your years starts with `08`.

Comment: What is the date you want the orders selected by? Seriously, what do you mean by '08'?

Comment: Try: `LIKE '%-08-%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a date calculation, you can say:

```
select * from orders_ where month(dateordered) = 8
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know about the `Month()` function. That'll come in handy, for sure. Does it work the same with `year()` or `day()`

Comment: You're welcome! Yep, `DAY()` and `YEAR()` are also built-in functions. :)